# Gulp disappearing everytime new modules installed

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Gulp installed locally (picture 1, 2). Everything working fine. After installing new modules (picture 3) Gulp disappears (picture 4). Starting Gulp with "npm run gulp".

Script from package.json:

```
"gulp": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp"
```

I have to reinstall Gulp everytime when I install more modules. Problem appears only with Gulp module.

Questions:

1. Why Gulp disappear everytime?
2. Is there any solution for this problem?

1. Installing Gulp.

[image: Picture 1]

2. node_modules/.bin/gulp.

[image: Picture 2]

3. Installing new module.

[image: Picture 3]

4. Gulp disappears from node_modules/.bin/.

[image: Picture 4]

Comment: What is your Node version? Do you have a package lock?

Comment: @fontophilic node v8.9.4, I have package-lock.json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved after installing latest version of Node.js.